# How to Change partial image area by HTML5/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, jquery-plugins

I am wondering to change one image map area with other image map area.
For example:
I have two images one is **selector.jpg**
[image]

Second image is **emoji,jpg**
[image]

I want to replace selected question mark with one clicked emoji from emoji.jpg.
Steps could be as follows:

1. Click any question mark in selector.jpg
2. emoji.jpg will be popped up
3. Click on one emoji
4. Question mark should be replaced with emoji

My code:

```
 <img src="selector.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
        <map name="image-map">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" onclick="javascript:alert('First')" href="#" coords="203,87,55" shape="circle">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" onclick="javascript:alert('Second')" href="#" coords="124,229,55" shape="circle">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" onclick="javascript:alert('Third')" href="#" coords="288,232,55" shape="circle">
        </map>
```

Please help me to complete this task.

Comment: i just make map areas but still unable to figure out how i can replace these question marks with emojies??

Comment: You could tinker a whole lot with margins and transforms to set the background of the ? with the emoji.jpg set to a certain zoom and cropping. I personally would have one image per emoji and forget about imagemaps, makes it easier and more complient with modern devices

Comment: Dear @user3154108, Actually, this is requirement to use only two images for all operation. please help me in this regard!

Comment: I would try moving a div of the right size with position absolute and top and left over the ? you want to cover and then set the emoji image as background, using background-size and other background properties to zoom in on the right emoji. Give it a try and come back when you have some Code to evaluate

Comment: Thanks @user3154108, idk how i will extract selected emoji. please help me with the ANSWER to do it by sparing your valuable time. please

Comment: You will have to map the image with an imagemap, setting your linkable areas, then you know what emoji was clicked. It is a bothersome and complex way, but it is well documented when you do a little research.